# ZendFramework Modules

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am having problems with modules, I searched the web but I can not get this to work.

This is my directory structure

```
Layout
application
  configs
  Modules
    default
        controllers
        models
        views
          helper
          scripts
             index
             error
        Bootstrap.php
    Bootstrap.php
docs
library
  DoctrineORM 2.1.5
test
```

My application.ini

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"

resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] =

resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

resources.router.routes.home.route = /home
resources.router.routes.home.default.module = default
resources.router.routes.home.default.controller = index
resources.router.routes.home.default.action = index

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

My Bootstap.php (all Bootstrap.php files are the same)

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap

}
```

All I get is an blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within a module based ZF application, there are two different types of Bootstrap files: application bootstrap and module bootstrap. This Bootstrap.php in your application directory should look like:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap {}
```

The Bootrap.php in each module directory should look like:

```
class ModuleName_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap {}
```

(ModuleName should be replaced with the name of the module).

It is also advisible to define the default module name and whether the default module has a namespace prefix:

```
resources.frontController.defaultmodule = "example"
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = 1
```

This tells the frontController that the default module is `example` and that all classes within that module are prefixed with `Example_`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your config looking at production settings, make sure to change

```
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
```

under your production tag

If your code looks exactly like what you posted, you are missing a curly bracket

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
}
```

If you are getting a blank page, 9 out of 10 times it's because display_errors aren't turned on. So you aren't seeing the error above.